# Vaadin shortcutListener same key multiple tables triggers only one

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using `addShortcutListener` function of table for key **TAB**.

If there's only one table in the page, everything works as expected. But if I put two or more tables with shortcut listeners (events doing different things) only one of them works, interestingly this is the first one.

```
Table table = new Table( "First One" ); 
table.addShortcutListener( new ShortcutListener( "First TAB", ShortcutAction.KeyCode.TAB, null ){

            @Override
            public void handleAction( Object sender, Object target ){
                Object targetParent = ( ( AbstractComponent )target ).getParent();
                if( ( targetParent != null ) && ( targetParent instanceof Table ) ){
                    //doing something
                }
            }
        } );
```

And the second:

```
Table table = new Table( "Second One" ); 
table.addShortcutListener( new ShortcutListener( "Second TAB", ShortcutAction.KeyCode.TAB, null ){

                @Override
                public void handleAction( Object sender, Object target ){
                    Object targetParent = ( ( AbstractComponent )target ).getParent();
                    if( ( targetParent != null ) && ( targetParent instanceof Table ) ){
                        //doing something
                    }
                }
            } );
```

When I focus the second table and press **TAB**, first table's event works.

Thanks in advance.